# Youtube analytics V1 API is suddenly returning null response. Tried with Youtube analytics V2 API aswell. Still same issue

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am not able to get any response from youtube analytics v1 API suddenly. It was working fine before.

Code -

```
string dimension = "country";
string requestedMetrics = "views,redViews,comments,likes,dislikes,videosAddedToPlaylists," +
            "videosRemovedFromPlaylists,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,estimatedRedMinutesWatched," +
            "averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,cardClickRate,cardTeaserClickRate,cardImpressions," +
            "cardTeaserImpressions,cardClicks,cardTeaserClicks,subscribersGained,subscribersLost";

ReportsResource.QueryRequest result = this.analyticsService.Reports
            .Query("channel==MINE", this.reportDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), this.reportDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), requestedMetrics);
        result.Dimensions = dimension;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(videoId) && videoId.ToLower() != "all")
        {
            result.Filters = $"video=={videoId}";
        }

        Google.Apis.YouTubeAnalytics.v1.Data.ResultTable resultTable = result.Execute();
```

The scopes getting used -

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsMonetaryReadonly, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly" };
```

I have seen youtube analytics v1 API will get deprecated on october 31st 2018. But till migration to v2 I need to fix the issue.

Comment: I have tried with analytics v2 api aswell. Still it's returning 0 rows.

Comment: If it was down you would be getting an error message.  If the response is a null then there is no data for your request.  Remove some of those metrics and try with only one.  say views and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for looking into. I have not got any error message. For simplicity, I have created a channel and uploaded a video. I have 4 views. I have tried this simple request, but still it's not returning any result - https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?dimensions=day&endDate=2018-09-21&ids=channel%253D%253DUCpV8LzmfVr-xiFHsuVEnO7Q&metrics=views&startDate=2018-09-21&_h=2&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are probably having is that you are checking to soon [Google apis exporer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?dimensions=day&endDate=2018-09-21&ids=channel%253D%253DUCpV8LzmfVr-xiFHsuVEnO7Q&metrics=views&startDate=2018-09-19&_h=6&)  You will need to set the start day to two at least two days ago.

It normally takes 24 - 48 hours for data to be processed you cant see this information for today for example.

For my own channel i am seeing

```
 "rows": [
  [
   "2018-09-18",
   1
  ],
  [
   "2018-09-19",
   2
  ]
```

To day is 2018-09-21 the most recent date i can get is the 19th which is two days ago.

Comment: Highly appreciate your help. I am able to see the result.

Comment: @DalmTo again I am seeing no result with another channel. Tried to fetch even I month old data too ,but didn't work. Source code - ReportsResource.QueryRequest result = this.analyticsService.Reports.Query();
            result.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            result.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-29).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            result.Ids = "channel==MINE";
            result.Dimensions = "day";
            result.Metrics = "views,redViews";
            result.Filters = $"video==all";
            var resultTable = result.Execute();